How could I possibly make my custom version of chromium check a XML Update server? And how can I fix An error occurred while checking for updates: 9
I'm currently trying to add an update server, however it isn't working properly. I change the code for fetch.py located in /chromium/src/third_party/updater/chromium_mac_arm64/3pp/fetch.py. However that didn't work. In addition to that even before the changes I am getting this error displayed in the About chromium section stating An error occurred while checking for updates: 9 (error code 0).
I am using Chromium
version 129.0.6664.0 (Developer Build) (arm64)
For the update server. I tried to change it to connect to my website and an XML file, I thought it would work but it didn't. The code is as follows #!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import functools
import json
import os
import sys
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

# MIN_VERSION is the earliest working version of the updater for self-update
# testing. If a backwards-incompatible change to the updater is made, it may be
# necessary to increase the version.
MIN_VERSION = 1290000  # Update this to a version number for testing

UPDATE_XML_URL = 'https://www.generalcodestudios.com/updates/trevin/trevin-update.xml'
LAST_CHANGE_URL = 'https://www.generalcodestudios.com/updates/trevin/trevin-last-change.txt'
UPDATER_ZIP_URL = 'https://www.generalcodestudios.com/updates/trevin/trevin-updater.zip'

def get_platform():
    return 'Mac_Arm'  # For ARM-based systems

def int_or_inf(v):
    try:
        return int(v.replace('.', ''))
    except ValueError:
        return -float('inf')

def fetch_from_xml(platform, minimum):
    """
    Fetches version information from the XML update file.
    """
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(UPDATE_XML_URL)
    xml_data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)
    
    min_version = float('inf')
    max_version = ''
    
    for version in root.findall('.//version'):
        version_text = version.text
        if int_or_inf(version_text) > minimum:
            min_version = min(min_version, int_or_inf(version_text))
        max_version = max(max_version, version_text)

    if min_version == float('inf'):
        min_version = None
    return min_version, max_version

def find(platform, minimum, maximum):
    """
    Returns a version from XML closest to `minimum` but not more than `maximum`
    for `platform`. May return maximum even if it does not exist in XML.
    """
    found_min = maximum
    pivot = str(minimum)
    while pivot < str(maximum):
        found, pivot = fetch_from_xml(platform, minimum)
        found_min = min(found_min, found)
    return found_min

def lastDatum(platform):
    """
    Returns a version from XML that only updates every n versions.
    """
    try:
        latest = int(urllib.request.urlopen(LAST_CHANGE_URL).read().decode('utf-8'))
    except ValueError:
        latest = MIN_VERSION
    return max(MIN_VERSION,
               find(platform, latest - latest % 1000, latest))

def print_latest():
    print(lastDatum(get_platform()))

def get_url():
    print(
        json.dumps({
            'url': [
                UPDATER_ZIP_URL
            ],
            'ext': '.zip',
            'name': ['updater.zip']
        }))

def main():
    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    sub = ap.add_subparsers()
    sub.add_parser('latest').set_defaults(func=lambda _opts: print_latest())
    sub.add_parser('get_url').set_defaults(func=lambda _opts: get_url())
    opts = ap.parse_args()
    return opts.func(opts)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())

What can I do?

Google Omaha server. I wouldn't do it from scratch but instead use what has already been built.

Yea @Asesh but I don't know how to do that either.

@Asesh so I do know what an Omaha server is, I have the git hub etc. However I'm unable to host the server on a personal device since I wan't to release this software, and I don't know where to put the IP

Ah, I have an idea.

Chromium update integration will be a big task. You will have to modify Chromium to interact with Google Omaha client (Windows only), for macOS, I don't think they have open sourced the update client. It's the update client which interacts with the server, not the browser. Google Omaha client for more information.

Greetings @Asesh. I've been doing some re-search. As I'm a Mac user I believe that Omaha uses a sparkle framework version. Even so, I haven't figured out how to setup Omaha even for the windows version of my fork of chromium. I have the tools. Just I don't know how to use them. Also. Is there a way to just remove that and for Mac just use sparkle and for windows make it launch a custom update EXE?

The Omaha server that is open source uses Python 2 which has been deprecated. Just follow the Crystalnix's tutorials, it might work: https://github.com/omaha-consulting/omaha-server

No. It Doesn't work, I may just make another app to handle updates. @Asesh
